ANTLR4 grammar issue for Iptables grammar file
I am trying to create an iptables parser using ANTLR4.
I wrote the grammar file and there were 5 errors that I can't resolve that are related to the parser rules.  The input for running this grammar file is antlr4 -Dlanguage=Cpp iptables.g4.
The errors are shown below:
error(50): iptables.g4::: syntax error: mismatched character ';' expecting '{'
error(50): iptables.g4:27:0: syntax error: unterminated rule (missing ';') detected at 'status_line :' while looking for rule element
error(50): iptables.g4::: syntax error: mismatched character ':' expecting '{'
error(50): iptables.g4:41:4: syntax error: mismatched input '|' expecting COLON while matching a lexer rule
error(50): iptables.g4:41:14: syntax error: '+' came as a complete surprise to me while matching rule preamble

The grammar file that I have written for the parser rules:
grammar iptables;

//Parser rules
parse
    :   rule+ EOF
    ;

rule
    :   chain_rule
    |   policy_rule
    |   append_rule
    |   status_line
    ;

chain_rule
    :   'iptables' '-N' chain_name
    ;

policy_rule
    :   'iptables' '-P' chain_name policy
    ;

append_rule
    :   'iptables' '-A' chain_name options
    ;

status_line
    :   'Chain' chain_name '(' 'policy' policy PACKET_COUNT 'packets,' BYTE_COUNT 'bytes)'
    ;

chain_name
    :   'INPUT' | 'FORWARD' | 'OUTPUT' | CUSTOM_CHAIN
    ;

policy
    :   'ACCEPT' | 'DROP' | 'QUEUE' | 'RETURN'
    ;

options_
    :   DEFAULT
    |   option+
    ;

option
    :   '-s' LOCATION
    |   '-d' LOCATION
    |   '-p' PROTOCOL
    |   '--dport' PORT
    |   '--sport' PORT
    |   '-j' policy
    ;


//Lexer Rules 

fragment OCTET
    :   '0' 
    |   [1-9] [0-9]?
    |   '1' [0-9] [0-9]?
    |   '2' [0-4] [0-9]?
    |   '25' [0-5]
    ;

IP_ADDRESS
    :   OCTET '.' OCTET '.' OCTET '.' OCTET
    ;

PORT
    :   [0-9]+
    ;

PROTOCOL
    :   TCP
    |   UDP
    |   ICMP
    ;

TCP
    :   'tcp'
    ;

UDP
    :   'udp'
    ;

ICMP
    : 'icmp'
    ;

PACKET_COUNT
    :   [0-9]+
    ;

BYTE_COUNT
    :   [0-9]+
    ;

LOCATION
    :   IP_ADDRESS
    |   'anywhere'
    ;

DEFAULT
    :   '--'
    ;

CUSTOM_CHAIN
    :   [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
    ;

WS
    :   [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
    ;



options is a reserved word in ANTLR. Change:
options
    :   DEFAULT
    |   option+
    ;

to:
options_
    :   DEFAULT
    |   option+
    ;

(or something other than options)

Thank you so much!! The error is now <error(50): iptables.g4::: syntax error: mismatched character ';' expecting '{'
error(50): iptables.g4:27:0: syntax error: unterminated rule (missing ';') detected at 'status_line :' while looking for rule element> both related to the status line

Please edit your original question and include a complete grammar (the grammar you posted at first was not complete: it has many missing rules)

I have re-edited it with all the grammar that I have. I am also quite new to ANTLR, so I am unsure if all my rules are correct. The mismatched character error occurred at the append rule,

You are still using options inside append_rule. Change it into options_

Thank you so much!!! That fixes everything, Also I am wondering if there is a way to determine if a word is reserved in ANTLR from the errors.  Do the errors always point to the line below (i.e. the error of options in the append was showing as an error at the status line)?

Yeah, I agree that in this case the error is rather vague. It is because when writing options, ANTLR expects an opening { to indicate the start of the options. Usually, the error message are more descriptive.

Once again thank you so much for your help!
